# Does the UITableView function visibleCells return custom cell data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview

I have a number of custom cell objects (subclasses of UITableViewCell) with a couple of values in them to allow for user interaction within individual cells (like steppers or something). These values are stored within the custom cell class, since calling up to the owner of the table view seemed like a bad idea at the time.

I know of the function (NSArray *) visibleCells. Will that allow me to access the data within the cell objects?

If not, how?

I'm assuming that I can use the built-in functions of the UITableView to pull returned UITableViewCells, but is that sufficent when I'm talking about a subclass of that called, say CustomizerCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function:

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Answers an array of index paths.  Those index paths can be used the same way your cellForRowAtIndexPath uses the passed index path to access your model.

```
MyObject *myCustomDataSupportingACell = [myDatasourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```